# Rewriting a Spring security deprecated, AuthenticationManager / HttpSecurity

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I've read some examples and docs on Spring security which i managed to rewrite a deprecated function on the SecurityFilterchain.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/SecurityConfigurerAdapter.html#and()

However in another function below im facing issue on not knowing how i can rewrite it in a lambda based configuration and would need help to rewrite this.

```
  @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    
       return http.getSharedObject(AuthenticationManagerBuilder.class)
               .userDetailsService(customUserDetailService)
               .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder())
               .and().build();
    
    }
```

Comment: if you have already defined what authentication you are using there is no need to set this and it can all be removed because spring security will already supply you with a predefined AuthenticationManager unless you have built a custom security solution which is in general bad practice and not recommended, and thats also the reason as to why there is no direct docs for it. As it is once again, not best practice to build custom security solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could rewrite `AuthenticationManager` Bean as next one it is going to work as expected.

```
  @Bean
  public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        AuthenticationManagerBuilder authManagerBuilder =  http.getSharedObject(AuthenticationManagerBuilder.class);
        authManagerBuilder.userDetailsService(customUserDetailService)
            .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        return authManagerBuilder.build();        
      }
```

More details about it and some references you will be able to find [spring-security-without-the-websecurityconfigureradapter](https://spring.io/blog/2022/02/21/spring-security-without-the-websecurityconfigureradapter) post.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `AuthenticationManagerBuilder`, please publish the `UserDetailsService` and `PasswordEncoder` beans separately like so:

```java
@Bean
UserDetailsService customUserDetailsService() {
    // ... construct
}

@Bean
PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    // ... construct
}
```

In your case, given that you are fine with the `AuthenticationProvider` defaults in `AuthenticationManager`, there is no need to construct one directly as you are doing.